# How do I update rows when clicking "update" button in web application gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In my web application ASP.NET, I so far have a gridview configured where I can delete rows (I have a primary identity(1,1) key set) and click the "edit" button to get a row to be editable, but I have no idea how to get the rows to update.

Basically, after the user edits a textbox in the web application's gridview, I'm not sure how to fetch that data, and write the code in VB.NET to attach it to the database.

Here's my HTML code for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="861px" 
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
                    SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Commission_Earned" HeaderText="Commission_Earned" 
                    SortExpression="Commission_Earned" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Commission_Rate" HeaderText="Commission_Rate" 
                    SortExpression="Commission_Rate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MSRP" HeaderText="MSRP" SortExpression="MSRP" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sale_Price" HeaderText="Sale_Price" 
                    SortExpression="Sale_Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Salesperson" HeaderText="Salesperson" 
                    SortExpression="Salesperson" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VIN" HeaderText="VIN" SortExpression="VIN" />

                         <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="Update" OnClick = "Button1_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Salesperson") + "," + Eval("VIN") + "," + Eval("Sale_Price") + "," + Eval("MSRP") + "," + Eval("Commission_Rate") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AutoDealer_MatthewBuhrConnectionString3 %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Commission Earned] AS Commission_Earned, [Commission Rate] AS Commission_Rate, [MSRP], [Sale Price] AS Sale_Price, [Salesperson], [VIN] FROM [Sales]"
            DeleteCommand="SELECT * FROM Sales" 
            UpdateCommand="">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Salesperson" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="MSRP" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CommissionRate" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CommissionEarned" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of adding 3 diffrent buttons, you could just write the line:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Update" EditText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-blue" />
```

Fill up the method

`UpdateCommand="UPDAE [Table] SET Salesperson=@Salesperson"`